# How to check undefined value when use preload and return no value with Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm doing phoenix framework with ecto.

I wrote following code.

```
    query = from m in Member,
                 where: m.member_id == ^member_id,
                 preload: [:assoc1, :assoc2, :assoc3]

    Repo.all(query)
```

When all preloaded `assocs` has related values in DB, it works.

However when preloaded `assocs` do not have related value, it returns null.
It cause error `function nil.assoc3/0 is undefined` in phoenix JSON view.

I would like to show JSON. I'm glad if I can get following JSON when `assoc3` value is nil for example.

```
[{"member_id":1, "assoc1":"xxx", "assoc2":"yyy", "assoc3":""}]
```

Please give me advice how to manage no related nil values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue does not seem to be with `assoc3` being `nil`. According to the error message, the view attempts to call `nil.assoc3` which means the database returned no result for the initial query (read: no `Member`.)

You should validate the response from the database and render different pages for a successfully returned `Member` vs. `nil`.